"Create Token" on Solana keeps resulting in "Segmentation fault"
Dear Solana Community
After spending hours in finding the root cause of "segmentation fault", I am finally posting this thread, while hoping to obtain a support.
As a matter of fact, running these commands (a priori, simple) still produce error:
spl-token create-token
Result: Segmentation fault
spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb create-token --enable-metadata
Result: Segmentation fault
From a Youtube tutorial
spl-token create-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb
Result: Segmentation fault
solana config get
===================================================
Config File: /root/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: https://api.devnet.solana.com 
WebSocket URL: wss://api.devnet.solana.com/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /root/.config/solana/demo.json 
Commitment: confirmed

spl-token --version
spl-token-cli 4.0.0

solana --version
solana-cli 2.0.3

I am very puzzled: I've used the Solana cli to create keys, deployed sample smart contracts, without encountering issues.
is it due to the fact that my wsl uses by default root@ leading to permission issues? In that case I've used chmod targeting /root/.config/solana/demo.json.
Many thanks in advance for your assistance, as I am running out of ideas.
Merry Christmas!

This was a bug, be sure to use a newer version of spl-token!
